# AngularJS - Function Expected or Object is not a Function

Tags: angularjs, promise

New to AngularJS and I guess I don't understand how to call one Promise method from another with the same factory. Every time my code gets to the $http.get within processPerson, I get a Function Expected error in IE, or an Object is not a Function error in Chrome. I've tried reorganizing code many times, multiple factories, etc, and generally get the same error. The only time I can get this to work is if I combine the functions where the processPerson function is embedded within the success of the getPersonnel.

Code:

```
(function(){

var app = angular.module('hrSite', ['personnel']);

app.controller('PersonnelController', function($scope, personnelFactory){
    var personnelPromise = personnelFactory.getPersonnel();
    personnelPromise.then(function(personnel){
        var perDefs = new Array();
        $.each(personnel.data.value, function( i, person ){
            var perDef = personnelFactory.processPerson(person);
            perDefs.push(perDef);
        });
        $q.all(perDefs).then(function(){
            $scope.personnel = personnel.data.value;
        });
    });
});

})();

(function(){

var personnelModule = angular.module('personnel', []);

personnelModule.factory('personnelFactory', function($http, $q) {

        var getPersonnel = function(){
            return $http.get("/sites/Development/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Personnel')/items");
        };

        var processPerson = function(person){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http.get("/sites/Development/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Personnel Skills')/items?$select=*,Skill/Id,Skill/Title&$filter=PersonId eq '"+person.Id+"'&$expand=Skill").then(function(skills){
                    person.Skills = skills.data.value;
                    person.SkillsId = [];
                    $.each(skills.data.value, function( j, skill ){
                        person.SkillsId.push(skill.Id);
                    });
                    deferred.resolve();
                });
            return deferred.promise();
        };
        return {getPersonnel: getPersonnel,
                processPerson: processPerson}
});
})();
```

Comment: $q is not injected into controller.

Comment: micronyks is correct, change the controller to `app.controller('PersonnelController', function($scope, personnelFactory,$q){`

Comment: Although true, that did not fix the error. The error I receive comes before that... specifically at:      $http.get("/sites/Development/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Personnel Skills')/items?$select=*,Skill/Id,Skill/Title&$filter=PersonId eq '"+person.Id+"'&$expand=Skill").then(function(skills){

Comment: Here is the full text of the IE error I get: TypeError: Function expected

   at processPerson (https://mysite.com/sites/Development/SiteAssets/js/scripts/personnel.js:21:5)

   at Anonymous function (https://mysite.com/sites/Development/SiteAssets/js/scripts/app.js:10:5)

   at each (https://mysite.com/sites/Development/_catalogs/masterpage/j3/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2:2873)

   at Anonymous function (https://mysite.com/sites/Development/SiteAssets/js/scripts/app.js:9:4)

   at Q (https://mysite.com/sites/Development/SiteAssets/js/libs/angular.min.js:100:230)

   at Q ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind - I figured it out. I was migrating code from a jQuery project and in jQuery, you return a promise like this:

```
return deferred.promise();
```

Since Angular has its own deferred feature, `$q`, I began using that, without realizing that the notation to return a promise was slightly different:

```
return deferred.promise;
```

No `()` in that, which was really screwing things up. Now everything seems to be working fine.